# Experiencing Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this vba code to loop through and copy and paste a new line every until it finds a zero keeps giving me a Run-time error '1004'. I can't quite figure out what is causing it. It breaks at `Sheets("Regular Invoice").Range("A29:N29").Copy` (According to using the F8 key) Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub BoxTest()

Dim testRow As Integer
Dim pasteRow As Integer


testRow = 2
pasteRow = 30
Worksheets("Boxes").Select
Do Until Worksheets("Boxes").Range(testRow, 13).Value = 0

Sheets("Regular Invoice").Range("A29:N29").Copy
Worksheets("Regular Invoice").Cells(pasteRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

testRow = testRow + 1
pasteRow = pasteRow + 1

Loop
testRow = testRow + 1
pasteRow = pasteRow + 1


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @MutjayLee has already an excellent answer I'd still like to throw in this additional solution for your consideration:

```
Sub BoxTest()

Dim testRow As Integer
Dim pasteRow As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long

pasteRow = 30

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Boxes")
    .Activate
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For testRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        If .Cells(testRow, 13).Value = 0 Then Exit For
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Regular Invoice")
            .Range("A29:N29").Copy Destination:=.Cells(pasteRow, 1)
        End With
        pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
    Next testRow
End With

'Not really necessary
'testRow = testRow + 1
'pasteRow = pasteRow + 1

End Sub
```

It avoids the `Do ... Loop` and exchanges it with a `For ... Next` with the option to exit beforehand if your condition is met. These loops are normally preferred as they are definite and not indefinite as `Do ... Loop`. If the condition is incorrectly set for a `Do ... Loop` they can easily run indefinitely and crash your Excel.

Comment: I believe that this does work, but it just won't seem to work for me. I keep receiving error 1004 when I try to run this.

Comment: Sorry, I did it again and used `Range` when there should have been `Cells`. I corrected the error. Now it should work.

Answer (score 3):

This line is the problem

```
Do Until Worksheets("Boxes").Range(testRow, 13).Value = 0
```

you can do either

```
Do Until Worksheets("Boxes").Cells(testRow, 13).Value = 0
```

or

```
Do Until Worksheets("Boxes").Range("M" & testRow).Value = 0
```

---

Only **Cells** takes the range as Row Number and Column Number.

**Range** Only takes number as Row, and Columns always have to be Letter

Comment: This was a working solution, thanks for the explanation on cells and range. Really helpful.